# Как написать правило в .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Здравствуйте.

мой .htaccess сейчас вот такой:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [R=301,L]

Options -Indexes
Options -Includes
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

и переменная $url для get параметров

```
$url = (isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null);
$url = rtrim($url, '/');
$url = explode('/', $url);
```

в $url[0] Я подключаю контроллер а в $url[1] модели контроллера.

я создал новый контроллер images и он доступен по адресу site.com/images, но проблема в том что у меня на сервере есть папка images и правило в htaccess не срабатывает и Apache не понимает что это контроллер, и выдает ошибку (Access forbidden!)

подскажите как и что нужно написать в htaccess чтоб решить данную проблему.

Comment: А как на счёт переименовать папку на сервере из images в img? Как по мне так это самый простой вариант! :)

Comment: к сожалению не вариант

Comment: в таком случае, вам нужно копать в сторону `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(png|jpg|gif)$`, если ссылка оканчивается форматом картинки, не переопределять её.